# Algorithm for particles targeting

Tags: language-agnostic, math, graphics, modeling, particles

I'm building a particles systems, one of the features I'd like to add is a "target" feature. What I want to be able to do is set an X,Y target for each particle and make it go there, not in a straight line though (duh), but considering all other motion effects being applied on the particle.

The relevant parameters my particles have:

- **posx, posy** : inits with arbitrary values. On each tick speedx and speedy are added to posx and posy respectively
- **speedx, speedy** : inits with arbitrary values. On each tick accelx and accely are added to speedx speedy respectively if any)
- **accelx, accely** : inits with arbitrary values. With current implementation stays constant through the lifespan of the particle.
- **life** : starts with an arbitrary value, and 1 is reduced with each tick of the system.

What I want to achieve is the particle reaching the target X,Y on it's last life tick, while starting with it's original values (speeds and accelerations) so the motion towards the target will look "smooth". I was thinking of accelerating it in the direction of the target, while recalculating the needed acceleration force on each tick. That doesn't feel right though, would love to hear some suggestions.

Comment: If you are wanting a gravity type effect then you would want to alter the `speed`s in the direction of the target by (in this model) setting the accelerations to 'point' at the target. Obviously for gravity you'd need to account for the separation ([inverse square rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law)). But for just a general motion you don't need to account for separation. What effect are you trying to achieve ultimately?

Comment: with a gravitational force the particles wouldn't reach the destination, but circle it for ever. Which is kind of fortunate for anybody living on the earth.

Comment: @El ronnoco - for gravity I'm using the accely property (which can also generate opposite effects). I'm trying to achieve a swarm-going-somewhere kind of effect.

Comment: @Jens Not strictly true. eg Two stationary masses which exert gravitational force on each other will attract directly toward each other and collide...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a "smooth" motion, you either keep the speed constant, or the acceleration constant, or the jerk constant. That depends on what you call "smooth" and what you call "boring". Let's keep the acceleration constant.

From a physics point of view, you have this constraint

```
targetx - posx = speedx*life + 1/2accelx * life * life
targety - posy = speedy*life + 1/2accely * life * life
```

Because distance traveled is `v*t+1/2at^2`. Solving for the unknown acceleration gives

```
accelx = (targetx - posx - speedx*life) / (1/2 * life * life)
accely = (targety - posy - speedy*life) / (1/2 * life * life)
```

(For this to work speedy must be in the same unit as time, for example "pixels per tick" and life is a number of "ticks". )

Since you use [euler integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method), this will not bring the particle exactly on the target. But I doubt it'll be a real issue.

Works like a charm:

[image: result]

Another picture, this time with constant jerk

```
jerkx = 6.0f*(targetx-x - speedx*life - 0.5f*accelx*life*life)/(life*life*life)
```

Looks like there is another bend in the curve...
[image]

Java code

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TargetTest extends JPanel {

  List<Particle> particles = new ArrayList<Particle>();
  float tx, ty; // target position

  public TargetTest() {

    tx = 400;
    ty = 400;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
      particles.add(new Particle(tx / 2 + (float) (tx * Math.random()), ty / 2
          + (float) (ty * Math.random())));

    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) tx * 2, (int) ty * 2));
  }

  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g1) {
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g1;
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    // comment next line to draw curves
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);

    for (Particle p : particles) {
      p.update();
      p.draw(g);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Particle tracking");
        final TargetTest world = new TargetTest();
        f.add(world);

        // 1 tick every 50 msec
        new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            world.repaint();
          }
        }).start();

        f.pack();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }

  class Particle {
    float x, y;// position
    float vx, vy;// speed
    float ax, ay;// acceleration
    float jx, jy;// jerk

    int life; // life

    float lastx, lasty;// previous position, needed to draw lines
    int maxlife; // maxlife, needed for color

    public Particle(float x, float y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      // pick a random direction to go to
      double angle = 2 * Math.PI * Math.random();
      setVelocity(angle, 2);// 2 pixels per tick = 2 pixels per 50 msec = 40
                            // pixels per second

      // the acceleration direction 'should' be close to being perpendicular to
      // the speed,
      // makes it look interesting, try commenting it if you don't believe me ;)
      if (Math.random() < 0.5)
        angle -= Math.PI / 2;
      else
        angle += Math.PI / 2;
      // add some randomness
      angle += (Math.random() - 0.5) * Math.PI / 10;
      setAcceleration(angle, 0.1);

      life = (int) (100 + Math.random() * 100);
      maxlife = life;
      lastx = x;
      lasty = y;
    }

    public void setVelocity(double angle, double speed) {
      vx = (float) (Math.cos(angle) * speed);
      vy = (float) (Math.sin(angle) * speed);
    }

    public void setAcceleration(double angle, double speed) {
      ax = (float) (Math.cos(angle) * speed);
      ay = (float) (Math.sin(angle) * speed);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void calcAcceleration(float tx, float ty) {
      ax = 2 * (tx - x - vx * life) / (life * life);
      ay = 2 * (ty - y - vy * life) / (life * life);
    }

    private void calcJerk(float tx, float ty) {
      jx = 6.0f * (tx - x - vx * life - 0.5f * ax * life * life)
          / (life * life * life);
      jy = 6.0f * (ty - y - vy * life - 0.5f * ay * life * life)
          / (life * life * life);
    }

    public void update() {
      lastx = x;
      lasty = y;
      if (--life <= 0)
        return;

      // calculate jerk
      calcJerk(tx, ty);
      // or uncomment and calculate the acceleration instead
      // calcAcceleration(tx,ty);

      ax += jx;
      ay += jy;// increase acceleration

      vx += ax;
      vy += ay;// increase speed

      x += vx;
      y += vy;// increase position
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
      if (life < 0)
        return;
      g.setColor(new Color(255 - 255 * life / maxlife, 
            255 * life / maxlife,0));
      g.drawLine((int) x, (int) y, (int) lastx, (int) lasty);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Ishtar I meant "smooth" as in not straight or "boring" as you've put it. Smooth means curved - the particle will initially start with it's own arbitrary speeds and acceleration values and gradually will shift it motion direction towards the target. It supposed to work in such a way that it will reach target on the last tick.

Comment: @MeLight - Yup, that's what i guessed. So try it out, if the initial speed is big enough, it will curve towards the target.

Comment: @Ishtar - Thanks! Can't wait to get home to try it out.

Comment: @MeLight - Glad you like it :)

Comment: @MeLight - [jerk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_%28physics%29) the rate of change of the acceleration, just like acceleration is the rate of change of speed, and speed is the rate of change of position. Like a constant velocity gives a line, constant acceleration gives a parabola, constant jerk gives a 'bit more complicated function'

Comment: @Ishtar - thanks for the info! I'd like to see the Java code btw

Comment: Kind of unrelated but interesting non the less. I learnt this from a doc on rollercoaster design. Acceleration=Rate Of Change of Speed. Jerk=ROCO Acceleration. Jolt=ROCO Jerk. Jounce=ROCO Jolt.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider that your particule is initially "applied" a force (Fv) which corresponds to the inertia it has from its initial velocity. Then you apply an attraction force (Fa) that is proportionnal to the distance to the target. You can then sum those forces, and given a particle weight, you can deduce acceleration to consider at time t.

```
Fa(t) = (Constant / distanceToTarget(t))* [direction to target]
Fv(t) = [initialForce] * dampening(t)
a(t) = (Fa(t) + Fv(t)) / mass
```

Then you can compute v(t) from v(t-1) and a(t) as usual

Edit: I forgot the life of the particle can directly be computed from the distance to the target (for instance: life = distance / initialDistance will go from 1 at start and approch 0 near the target)

Edit: You could think of this as a kind of magnet. See [wikipedia for the force formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets#Force_between_two_magnetic_poles).

Comment: Hi marvin, I need to calculate the the motion variables (path?) from the life variable, and not vice versa

Comment: With this method, you are computing each time an attraction force from the current position. Which will affect the next position. So I stand correct, you are computing here a "natural" motion that will reach the target. Effect will be kind of like if you place a metal ball near a powerfull magnet.

Answer (score 1):

one kind of movement you can use is the uniform acceleration http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration#Uniform_acceleration

Your particles will make a smoth move towards the target and hit it with rather high velocity

For meeting your stated criteria, do the following:

- calculate the distance from the target, the particle will have at the end of it's life time, assuming the speed doesn't change from now on.
- this distance put in this equation: http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/6/2/9/6295e1819e6bfe1101506caa4b4ec706.png and solve it for a
- use this as your acceleration
- Do this seperately for x and y